# Delphi How To Use Microsoft Speech Recognition API

Tags: delphi

I need some help with my code, my application supposed to get my voice and write everything i say in a TMemo component, but it's simply doesn't do anything 
Here is my code:
Am using SAPI 5.4 **Microsoft Speech Object Library**

```
procedure TForm1.initRecognizer;
begin
    // Create Voice Handler
    SpVoice := TSpVoice.Create(nil);
    //**//
    // Create Reconizer Context
    SpInProcRecoContext := TSpInProcRecoContext.Create(nil);
    SpInProcRecoContext.OnHypothesis  := SpInProcRecoContextHypothesis;
    SpInProcRecoContext.OnRecognition := SpInProcRecoContextRecognition;
    //**//
    // Create Grammar Rule
    RecoGrammar := SpInProcRecoContext.CreateGrammar(0);
    RecoGrammar.DictationSetState(SGDSActive);
    //**//
end;

procedure TForm1.SpInProcRecoContextHypothesis(ASender: TObject;
  StreamNumber: Integer; StreamPosition: OleVariant;
  const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
begin
     Memo1.Text := Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(0,-1,true);
end;

procedure TForm1.SpInProcRecoContextRecognition(ASender: TObject;
  StreamNumber: Integer; StreamPosition: OleVariant;
  RecognitionType: SpeechRecognitionType; const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
begin
    SpInProcRecoContext.Recognizer.AudioInput := Result;
    Memo1.Text := Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(0,-1,true);
end;
```

Please If there's a fix Will appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't know what `TSpVoice` is. Please provide a [mcve] and consider debugging your code.

Comment: spvoice is component from Microsoft Speech Object Library imported into Delphi
See Edit

Comment: The [`ISpRecoGrammar::SetDictationState()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee413306(v=vs.85)) documentation says: "*If an application uses an InProc recognizer, **it must call `ISpRecognizer::SetInput` with a non-NULL setting** before the recognizer will return recognitions, regardless of the dictation topic state.*" I don't see you doing that. MSDN examples also show [`ISpRecoGrammar::LoadDictation()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee413304(v=vs.85)) called before `SetDictationState()`. You are not doing that, either.

Comment: The edit doesn't much help. Spend some time reading the documentation, debugging, reading and running example code that works.

Comment: @halocedark Have you checked to make sure that the voice recognition that is built into Windows even works first. You see not all windows localization languages have support for speech recognition. So unless you have at least one language pack that support speech recognition installed on your Windows machine you can forget about doing any speech recognition with SAPI.

Comment: i'm using windows 10 and also tested speed recognition and works fine, any simle code will help